# Why does a small pickled nested dictionary use a lot of memory?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

If I have a nested dictionary, then the size of the cPickle'd file is much smaller than the memory used by the python process when I load it into memory. (I am referring to the Memory column in Windows 7 task manager.)

For example, one file of 28MB seems to turn into 202MB of memory. Another file of 155MB takes 1.50GB in memory.

Any pointers on why this is happening, and how I can reduce this inflation?

These nested dictionary contains only integer keys, and values are either integers or other nested integer dictionaries.

Comment: I guess this happens because the pickle file only contains the actual data that is stored, whereas at runtime python allocates a hashtable for each dictionary, which requires memory beyond what is needed for the actual data.

Comment: Depending on your data you may be able to use lists (if set of keys at each level is more-or-less contiguous) or a binary tree - either would reduce memory use at expense of making insert and lookup operations slower.

Comment: maybe you can provide more concrete information about the content of the dict? Of course, don't paste the 28MB here, but could you describe it more precise then with being "nested"? Maybe some samples with "..." in there.

Comment: To complete the partial answer of Steve, the integers are also expanded from just 32/64-bit of data to a full object (3 words of memory) plus a pointer to them.

Comment: @SteveAllison If you make an answer out of your comments, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Have you tried loading the same data with PyPy? Considering what @ArminRigo pointed out, PyPy might be able to optimise the memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider giving `objgraph` a try: it allows you to inspect what's going on in your program's memory; it can generate visual output too.

See http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/ for more information.